# pthread_cond_timedwait ignores cancellation request

Tags: c, macos, pthreads, posix

I've got a strange problem with pthread_cond_timedwait(): according to the POSIX specification it is a cancellation point. However, when I'm calling pthread_cancel() on the thread, it never gets cancelled! Instead, pthread_cond_timedwait() continues to run normally. It doesn't lock or anything, it just keeps running as if pthread_cancel() had never been called. As soon as I insert a pthread_testcancel() call, however, the thread gets cancelled correctly! Without the call to pthread_testcancel(), the thread is never cancelled although I'm calling pthread_cond_timedwait() all the time.

Does anybody have an idea what's going wrong here? Thanks a lot!

EDIT: Here comes the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

// replacement function because OS X doesn't seem to have clock_gettime()
static int clock_gettime(int clk_id, struct timespec* t)
{
    struct timeval now;
    int rv = gettimeofday(&now, NULL);

        if(rv) return rv;

    t->tv_sec = now.tv_sec;
        t->tv_nsec = now.tv_usec * 1000;

    return 0;
}

static void *threadproc(void *data)
{
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_mutexattr_t attr;               
    pthread_cond_t cond;

    pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
    pthread_mutexattr_settype(&attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE);

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, &attr);      
    pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&attr);

    pthread_cond_init(&cond, NULL);

    for(;;) {

        struct timespec ts;

        clock_gettime(0, &ts);

        // wait 60ms
        ts.tv_nsec += 60 * 1000000;

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        pthread_cond_timedwait(&cond, &mutex, &ts);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);   

#if 0
        pthread_testcancel();
#endif      
    }

    return NULL;    
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t pThread;

    pthread_create(&pThread, NULL, threadproc, NULL);

    printf("Waiting...\n");
    sleep(5);
    printf("Killing thread...\n");

    pthread_cancel(pThread);
    pthread_join(pThread, NULL);

    printf("Ok!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post code for a small example that shows the problem and let us know what platform you're dealing with.

Comment: Are you 'playing' with the thread's (or its parent's) cancel-type and -state?

Comment: Code posted. If you enable the call to pthread_testcancel(), everything will work fine. Otherwise the thread will never get cancelled.

Comment: See what happens if you increase the time out from 60ms to 60s, just for testing.

Comment: Also adding error checking might be a good idea, to see what else might go wrong.

Comment: Doesn't change anything. Thread doesn't get killed either. I've left out error checking for readability reasons. I've checked all return values. Everything is fine.

Comment: Have you tried pthread_cleanup_push/pop?  Maybe it only works with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your expectations about how the code should behave are correct, and in fact it works as expected on other systems I just tested. I think you've just found (yet another) bug in OSX.

Comment: I feared that :( Still strange that such basic functionality as cancelling a thread seems to be broken.

Comment: That's nothing compared to `sem_init` silently failing to do anything and giving you crashes when you try to use semaphores... It's really sad. Until the advent of OSX and now Android, all *nix systems had moved almost completely in the direction of POSIX conformance, and things were getting to the point where you could just write to POSIX and have your code work anywhere. But now, OSX and Android are thumbing their noses at standards and putting out pseudo-POSIX implementations that don't run anything but their walled-garden junkware...

Comment: http://lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-serlevel/2004/Mar/msg00016.html - Pretty Old. But discusses the same issue. It apears pthread_testcancel alone is the cancellation point in Mac OS.

Comment: @jay: You lost a `u` in the url, http://lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-userlevel/2004/Mar/msg00016.html

Comment: Link isn't working. And if that's true, it's incredibly broken and defeats the whole point of cancellation, which is to be able to interrupt a thread that's stuck in an operation that will possibly never complete.

Comment: Wow, now that I can read it, the situation is even worse. Making `pthread_setcancelstate` a cancellation point will cause extremely dangerous code breakage (memory leaks, state corruption, etc.).

Comment: There's also this: http://www.openradar.me/5610812 - http://lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-kernel/2007/Nov/msg00104.html

Comment: @Hasturkun: Wow, that thread is full of epic failure to understand thread cancellation from what seems to be the folks responsible for implementing it...

Answer (score 0):

`pthread_cancel` functions correctly in OS X 10.11.4 (and possibly earlier versions). In addition, the `value_ptr` argument of `pthread_join` returns `PTHREAD_CANCELED`, as should be expected.